# Узнавать новости ИЗ телевизора или ПО телевизору?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, выбор-варианта

Узнавать новости ***из*** телевизора или ***по*** телевизору?
Какой предлог лучше употребить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть одна (и только одна) ситуация, когда уместна формулировка "из телевизора": если ставится задача придать сказанному нотку сарказма. Того же эффекта можно достичь, если в традиционном варианте "по телевизору" вместо слова "телевизор" использовать сленговый вариант "ящик". Еще более сильный эффект получится, если совместить оба этих подхода.
Примеры (в порядке усиления сарказма):

> - Ты узнал об этом из новостей по телевизору?
>
> - Ты это узнал из телевизора?
>
> - Тебе это в новостях по ящику сказали?
>
> - Откуда ты это взял? Из ящика услышал?

Во всех остальных случаях - только **"по телевизору"**.

Answer (score 1):

По телевизору - норма, из телевизора - разговорное, всё-таки это новости из телепередач, а не из телевизора, это метонимия, которую ярким тропом не назовёшь.

Comment: использование в газете - это прям ошибкой считается?

Comment: В газете как хроника - ошибка, если что-то бытовое (герой узнал из телевизора) - пойдёт. Корреспондент должен говорить нормативно, герою можно.

Answer (score 1):

**узнава́ть**
*глаг., нсв., употр. очень часто*
познание
**1.** Когда вы что-то или о чём-то узнаёте, значит, вы получаете информацию от кого-либо о чём-либо или обращаетесь к кому-либо за сведениями о ком-либо, о чём-либо.
**Узнавать что-либо из газет, по радио, по телевидению.**
[Толковый словарь Дмитриева](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/5560/%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Узнавать из передачи по радио; узнавать из программы по телевидению (в обиходе: по телевизору) — при упрощении, пропуске **из** [чего?] остается **по**.

*Крымск уходил под воду, а чиновники узнавали о потопе по телевизору.

В Астане школьники смогут узнавать об отмене занятий по телевизору и через Интернет.*